# Mail client blocked by spamhaus

Tags: java, email

I need to send emails with Java and running into a problem I can't seem to fix. I get the following error message:

> javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
>     nested exception is:
>       com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable; client [xx.xx.xx.xx] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org

The part I don't understand is, above IP address masked as `xx.xx.xx.xx` actually is my development computers public IP address and is not connected to the mail server I'm using in any way.

The mail server is my own, I'm able to send mail via all other channels I've tried (node.js app, email-client, ...) and the server is not in any blocked list.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
public class SendMailExample {

    public void sendMail(String smtpHost,String username,String password,String senderAddress,String recipientsAddress,String subject,String text ){
        MailAuthenticator auth = new MailAuthenticator(username, password);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, auth);

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress));
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(
                    recipientsAddress, false));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setHeader("Test", "Test");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date( ));
            Transport.send(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }

    class MailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        // more code - I think unrelated 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "xxx@xxx.com";
        String password = "pass";
        String senderAddress ="xxx@xxx.com";
        String recipientsAddress = "some@one.com"; 
        String subject = "Test";
        String text = "text";
        String smtpHost = "smtp.myMailServer.com";
        new SendMailExample().sendMail(smtpHost, username, password, senderAddress, recipientsAddress, subject, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to get a network trace to see if you are really being connected to the internal address of the mail server.

Comment: The mail server may use the supplied computer name and reverse lookup returns the public IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the following:

Added:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

To the properties part and instead of

```
Transport.send(msg);
```

I'm now using

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(smtpHost, 587, username, password);
msg.saveChanges();
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```